# Field's value of native query in JPA

Tags: orm, jpa, field, native

How to get value of some fields in a native query (JPA)?

For example I want to get name and age of customer table:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name,age FROM customer WHERE id=...");
```

**Note: I don't want to map results to entities. I just want to get the value of the field.**

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A native query with multiple select expressions returns an `Object[]` (or `List<Object[]>`). From the specification:

> #### 3.6.1 Query Interface
>
> ...
>
> The elements of the result of a Java
>   Persistence query whose SELECT clause
>   consists of more than one select
>   expression are of type `Object[]`. If
>   the SELECT clause consists of only one
>   select expression, the elements of the
>   query result are of type Object. When
>   native SQL queries are used, the SQL
>   result set mapping (see section
>   3.6.6), determines how many items (entities, scalar values, etc.) are
>   returned. If multiple items are
>   returned, the elements of the query
>   result are of type `Object[]`. If only a
>   single item is returned as a result of
>   the SQL result set mapping or if a
>   result class is specified, the
>   elements of the query result are of
>   type `Object`.

So, to get the name and age in your example, you'd have to do something like this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name,age FROM customer WHERE id = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, customerId);
Object[] result = (Object[])q.getSingleResult();
String name = result[0];
int age = result[1];
```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 3.6.1 "Query Interface"
  - Section 3.6.6 "SQL Queries"

Comment: in line "Object[] result = q.getSingleResult(); " I have error: required Object[] found Object!

Comment: I solved it by casting:
Object[] result = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

Comment: @Navid Ah, yes, my code was missing a cast, didn't write it in an IDE.

Comment: Is there a way to map the above query with class 'Customer' {name, age, sex} without casting Object to any class? I mean the result set should be like JQL.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the JPA implementation. Hibernate does it different than castor, for example.
Here's a example how it would work in Hibernate:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select s.stock_code from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

I don't think that it is possible to get a plane value such as an integer... but this one should come very close to it.